# MongoDb Realm only sync certain schemas

Tags: mongodb-realm

I want to create App using MongoDB Realm,

But I don't want to sync the entire of my realm collections to the Cloud, some of it must only available locally, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

open a non-sync realm
[see doc here](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/react-native/open-a-realm/#open-a-local--non-synced--realm)